# Varnish MISS cache and Varnish control terminal is not responding at 192.168.56.102 on port 6082

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-6, varnish, varnish-vcl

I am using varnish on one box (192.168.56.102) and apache on other box (192.168.56.105).
on varnish box - in /etc/varnish/default.vcl

```
backend default {
.host = "192.168.56.105";
.port = "80";
}
```

and /etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,3G"
```

Question 1. Varnish not Caching (MISS)

```
When i access 192.168.56.102 it MISS cache and goes to apache box.

curl -I http://192.168.56.102  [vernish box]

HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
Server: Apache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="iExplore Development"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Pad: avoid browser bug
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 16:01:25 GMT
X-Varnish: 587747945
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: MISS
```

Question 2. Varnish control terminal is not responding 
    on apache (using drupal-pressflow-6) box - varnish admin (/admin/settings/varnish)

```
  VARNISH CONTROL TERMINAL: 192.168.56.102:6082

  entered VARNISH CONTROL KEY:

  Save configuration

  STATUS: The Varnish control terminal is not responding at 192.168.56.102 on port 6082.
```

Thanks in advance

[EDIT] - **@casperOne - can you please confirm why did you closed this question?** I have not found any valid answer for my question, this is disgrace to me